# Ionic 4 Default menu is hidden, how can I open menu from icon

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have create Ionic 4 app. The problem is, I don't want it to show the menu by default and I have hide that menu using the below code:

```
// Below code wll remove the menu bar
   ionViewWillEnter() {
   this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
 }
```

But, my purpose is to show the menu icon, on clicking that icon i want the menu to be opened, how can i manage this ?

### Edit 1

My `home.page.ts` code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {UserProvider} from '../../providers/user/user';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
//import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {


  constructor(public user:UserProvider,public menuCtrl: MenuController) {
    console.log("inside constructor");
    this.user.call_service('data').subscribe(datac => {
      console.log(datac);
    })

}

// Below code wll remove the menu bar
// ionViewWillEnter() {
//   this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
// }

}
```

`home.page.html` code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Home
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-card class="welcome-card">
      <img src="./assets/shapes.svg" alt="" />
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-subtitle>Get Started 5 ..</ion-card-subtitle>
        <ion-card-title>Welcome to Ionic</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <p>..Now that your app has been created, you'll want to start building out features and components. Check out some of the resources below for next steps.</p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
    <ion-list lines="none">
      <ion-list-header>
        <ion-label>Resources</ion-label>
      </ion-list-header>
      <ion-item href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/">
        <ion-icon slot="start" color="medium" name="book"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Ionic Documentation</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/scaffolding">
        <ion-icon slot="start" color="medium" name="build"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Scaffold Out Your App</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/structure">
        <ion-icon slot="start" color="medium" name="grid"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Change Your App Layout</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/basics">
        <ion-icon slot="start" color="medium" name="color-fill"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Theme Your App</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

### Edit 2

`app.component.ts` code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import {UserProvider} from '../providers/user/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  connection: any;

  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Home',
      url: '/home',
      icon: 'home'
    },
    {
      title: 'List',
      url: '/list',
      icon: 'list'
    },
    {
      title: 'Party Master',
      url: '/partym',
      icon: 'list'
    }

  ];

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar


  ) 

  {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

### Edit 3

`app.component.html`

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane>
    <ion-menu type="overlay">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

Comment: Please Explain more. if you want to show menu then why are you hiding it by `this.menuCtrl.enable(false);`?

Comment: because it is showing on left side by default, i want it to open with toggle button

Comment: please share your code. html and .ts both.

Comment: edited the question you can see there

Comment: also share your `app.component.html`

Comment: Edited the question again with `app.component.ts`  code

Comment: `HTML` not `.ts`

Comment: sorry Edit 3:: added `app.component.html`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201584/discussion-between-najam-us-saqib-and-user2828442).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using it as Website you can hide you menu like this:
inside your `app.component.html`

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane when="false">  // ADD FALSE on your split-pane tag it will hide menu
    <ion-menu type="overlay">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```